# Find content inside custom characters

Tags: jquery

How can I make sur to select all text inside `{{` and `}}` ?

For example:

```
{{BANANA}}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. You are probably looking for [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)